# Converting from Sql to Linq

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have, what I thought was a pretty straight-forward query.

In normal Sql this would read:

```
SELECT    [column names]
FROM      agentscheduledetail
WHERE     (date = '2012-07-04') AND 
           (
            exception = 'Break (No Sign Off)' OR
            exception = 'Break' OR
            exception = 'Break (Signed Out)'
           )
```

This returns approx 900 records.

However, when I try to enter this into my controller, I end up with around 300,000 records - so I think my AND and ORs are not working.  I've tried Linqer, but can't get it to work (I'm aware this may not be actual LINQ but the equivalent query in VS - if there is a linq version... I'd be grateful for that too if possible).

My controller query is:

```
        var dte = DateTime.Today;

        return View(db.agentscheduledetails.Where
           (
            d => d.date == dte && d.agentName.StartsWith("ta") && 
             (
              d.exception == "Break (No Sign Off)" || 
              d.exception == "Break" || 
              d.exception == "Break (Signed Out)"
             )
            ).ToList()
           );
```

Can anyone either a) let me know where I'm going wrong with my && || (and/or), or b) is there a way of stepping through the code in VS, to see what the above query translates to in normal SQL so I can try to figure out where I'm going wrong?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: try using .Contains() to check string

Comment: You haven't specified whether you're using LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework - but either way, yes, there are ways of looking at the generated SQL. See `DataContext.Log` for example in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Setup the DB context to output sql queries to a log file or the debugger windows. Check that's correct.

Comment: Hi - it is the Entity Framework - I generated my classes, and clicked Add controller in VS, and let it build the default controller code using EF.  All I am trying to do is filter the basic query it generates in the GET method.  Contains returns the same.  How do you setup the DB Context to output queries - the DBContext was also setup automatically by VS when I created the controller.  Thanks.

Comment: if you do create a query object e.g. var q=...where... (missing out the ToList() on the end.  Visual Studio debugger will show you the Generated SQL if you inspect the value.

Comment: I take it the extra `d.AgentName.StartsWith("ta")` is deliberate because its not in your SQL?

Comment: Remove the startswith, any change? You don't have that in your initial query. Also the miniprofiler and visual studio's intellitrace can both display the queries for EF if you are using the entity framework. Also the EF Profiler trial can be used as well but the other methods work great and miniprofiler is free and installed via Nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is perhaps a simplified version of what you are trying to do, also your LINQ contains an additional statement compared to the SQL where it is comparing the agent name?

```
var currentDate = DateTime.Today;
var exceptionTypes = new List<string>() { "Break (No Sign Off)", 
                                          "Break", "Break (Signed Out)" };

db.agentscheduledetails.Where(d => d.date == currentDate && 
                                           exceptionTypes.Contains(d.exception));
```

One thing that you could try is getting hold of a copy of LinqPad, this will let you run your LINQ statement against a database and will show you what the generated SQL statement is.

Comment: hi - thanks - that works perfect.  Can you not use && and || in the statements I was making? (I'll mark as answer as soons as SO allows) - cheers, Mark

Comment: If I run something similar in LinqPad then I get the desired result and the correct SQL.  I'm not sure about your set up though, if it's the Entity Framework then I'm not sure what will be happening, but in normal Linq to SQL it should work fine?  This method tends to be the preferred though as it's generally simpler to write.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from anything else,

```
    d.agentName.StartsWith("ta")
```

does not appear in your original sql...?

Comment: you're correct - I added that to see if it would filter the records anymore - it didn't...